# Show a first letter in django template

Tags: python, django, templates

I am trying to show a first letter of each member of a QuerySet in a django template:

```
views.py:

deparmtents = Department.objects.all()
context = {'department_list': departments}
return render(request, 'review/index.html', context)



index.html:

<table>
    {% for dept in department_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ dept.name[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ dept }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

However when I try to render the page there is an error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/review/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'dept.name[0]'
```

Should I manipulate the QuerySet before passing it to the template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work: `{{ dept.name.0 }}`

Docs say:

> > Technically, when the template system encounters a dot, it tries the following lookups, in this order:
> >     
> > Dictionary lookup
> > Attribute lookup
> > Method call
> >         
> > List-index lookup

[Reference link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables)